# How to create two subgraphs from a given graph

Tags: r, igraph, subgraph

Suppose a given directed graph `G` with `N` vertices and `M` edges.
How is it possible to create from the existing `M` connections of the graph `G` two subgraphs `S_1` and `S_2`. These respective subgraphs each have half of the existing edges. Furthermore it is determined by randomness, whether an edge belongs to `S_1` or `S_2`.

Example:

```
G <- erdos.renyi.game(5,p=0.5,directed = TRUE)
E(G)
> + 12/12 edges:
> [1] 1->5 2->1 4->1 5->1 1->2 3->2 5->2 1->3 3->5 5->3 2->4 3->4
```

Of the `12` existing edges should randomly `M/2=6` edges be selected, which are representing the Edges in `S_1`. The remaining `6` edges provide the edges is of `S_2`.

Comment: What should happen to the nodes connecting the edges of the subgraphs? Should be repeated in S_1 and S_2 ? e.g. `G = A->B->C`, `S_1 = A->B`, `S_2 = B->C` so, should node `B` present both in `S_1` and `S_2` ?

Comment: Yes, node B should be present in both.

Comment: the Adjacency Matrix of S_1 and S_2 should have the dimensions N*N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding you:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1)     # for reproducible example
G <- erdos.renyi.game(5,p=0.5,directed = TRUE) 
E(G) 
# Edge sequence:
#           
# [1] 1 -> 5
# [2] 3 -> 1
# [3] 3 -> 2
# [4] 4 -> 2
# [5] 1 -> 3
# [6] 2 -> 3
# [7] 3 -> 5
# [8] 2 -> 4
# [9] 5 -> 4

eids <- sample(1:ecount(G), ecount(G)/2)
S1 <- subgraph.edges(G, eids)
S2 <- subgraph.edges(G, (1:ecount(G))[-eids])
E(S1)
# Edge sequence:
#           
# [1] 1 -> 5
# [2] 3 -> 2
# [3] 4 -> 2
# [4] 5 -> 4
E(S2)
# Edge sequence:
#           
# [1] 3 -> 1
# [2] 1 -> 3
# [3] 2 -> 3
# [4] 3 -> 5
# [5] 2 -> 4
```